# Why does the binary search method give me an error if i put in a value that is not defined in the array?

Tags: java, binary-search

The binary search method is driven by a userInput in the variable value. It is then put through the binary search method which finds the value that is given by the user. Although It works properly when I put in a value defined by the array, when I put in a value that is not defined by the array I am given an error. I would like to prevent this but I don't know where to start attempting this issue.

the error that I receive is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at project.project.binarySearchAscending(project.java:99)
        at project.project.binarySearchAscending(project.java:107)
        at project.project.binarySearchAscending(project.java:107)
        at project.project.main(project.java:31)
```

this is the code for my project

```
package project;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int Size;//size of the array
        int order; // ascending or descending order
        int value;//this is for the value that you are looking for
        System.out.println("Put in the amount of expenses you have");
        Size = sc.nextInt();//User input for the amount of expenses
        System.out.println("put in all your expenses");
        int userInput[] = new int[Size];// what the users expenses are
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++)//This loop is for if the i value is smaller than user input then put in more values to complete the array
            userInput[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("do you want it ascending or descending order. If you want it in ascending press 1 or if you want descending press 2");
        order = sc.nextInt();// select if they wanted it in ascending or descending order
        System.out.print("expenses not sorted : ");
        printExpenses(userInput);//this is the method that prints out all the expenses
        if (order == 1) {
            expensesAscending(userInput);// If order is equal to one then sort in ascending else if it is equal to 2 then order it descending
        } else if (order == 2) {
            expensedescending(userInput);

        }
        System.out.println("what value are you looking for");
        value = sc.nextInt();
        if (order == 1) {int ans = binarySearchAscending(userInput, 0, Size, value);//use the binary search ascending method
        System.out.println(ans);
        if(ans == -1)
            System.out.println("value not found");
          else
            System.out.println("your expense is found at "  + ans + " and the value of the array is " + userInput[ans]);
    }else if (order==2) {int ans = binarySearchDescending(userInput, 0, Size, value);//use the binary search descending method
    System.out.println(ans);
    if(ans == -1)
        System.out.println("value not found");
      else
        System.out.println("your expense is found at " + ans + "and the value of the array is " + userInput[ans]);

    }}


    public static void printExpenses(int[] arr) {
        // this is were it is printed
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {//loops when i = to 0 and i is less than the length of the array then you should add one to the i value so that it could print out the entire array
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "$");
        }
    }

    public static void expensedescending(int arr[]) {
        // This is were the selection sort starts
        int N = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int small = arr[i];
            int pos = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > small) {
                    small = arr[j];
                    pos = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            System.out.println(": ");
            // Printing array after pass
            printExpenses(arr);
        }
    }

    public static void expensesAscending(int arr[]) {
        //insertion sort
        int N = arr.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            int j = i - 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            while (j >= 0 && temp < arr[j]) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
                ;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
            System.out.println(": ");
            // Printing array after pass
            printExpenses(arr);
        }
    }
    static int binarySearchAscending(int[] array, int left, int right, int key) {
        if (left > right) {
          return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (array[mid] == key) {
          return mid;
        }

        if (array[mid] > key) {
          return binarySearchAscending(array, left, mid - 1, key);
        }

        return binarySearchAscending(array, mid + 1, right, key);
      }


    static int binarySearchDescending(int[] array, int left, int right, int key) {
        if (left > right) {
          return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (array[mid] == key) {
          return mid;
        }

        if (array[mid] > key) {
          return binarySearchDescending(array, mid + 1, right, key);
        }

        return binarySearchDescending(array, left, mid - 1, key);
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: I think there's probaby an off-by-one error in there somewhere.  An array of size *N* is indexed by 0 ... *N* - 1.  I suspect your binary search methods expect 'right' to be the index of the last valid index, but you're calling them with right = Size, i.e., the first invalid index.

Comment: I have put in the error that I received

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if (order == 1) {int ans = binarySearchAscending(userInput, 0, Size, value);//use the binary search ascending method
```

You want your upper bound to be **Size - 1** not **Size**, like so:

```
if (order == 1) {int ans = binarySearchAscending(userInput, 0, Size-1, value);//use the binary search ascending method
```

You should see that this works for all cases.  The same problem exists in your call to **binarySearchDescending**.